# Swift_RfcComplianceException on valid email address, works in Windows not in Ubuntu

Tags: php, exception, symfony, swiftmailer, rfc2822

I'm running into what appears to be a rather infamous issue with SwiftMailer:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘Swift_RfcComplianceException’ with message ‘Address in mailbox given [noreply@host.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.’`

The message is being created with the following code (effectively):

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
         ->setSubject('Subject')
         ->setFrom(array('noreply@host.com' => 'Host'))
         ->setTo('recipient@gmail.com');
...
```

The odd thing is that the address: *noreply@host.com* does not fail the addr-spec regex on a local machine running Xampp in a Windows environment, but does fail on an Ubuntu machine running the Xampp solution out of `/opt/lampp`.

- This does not appear to be a problem with the PCRE version (both the same) because when I extract the `add-spec` to a string and run that through a simple script to parse, it passes.
- There are no extra characters, no untrimmed white space in the email addresses.

**UPDATE**:

Looking at the Apache logs I think I may have found the underlying issue:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: internal error: previously-checked referenced subpattern not found at offset 4246 in /home/ubuntu/.../vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php on line 354, referer: http://...

So on Windows, the regex compiles fine but on Linux it does not; unless it is extracted and the appropriate escapes put in.

Found a few issues on Github related to this:

- https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/279
- https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/259

Seems to be complaining about the subpattern after the `@` sign. One of the comments in the above referenced Github issues seems to imply that the error is being thrown when Apache processes the regex, which fits with what I've experienced on an Ubuntu 12.10 system (though not on Windows).

Could this have to do with Apache not having the right PCRE support or it being configured incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently investigating a similar error. All solutions I could find involved switching to another configuration/version of Apache but I find this very unstatisfying. You don't happen to still know the exact configuration of your Apache producing that error, don't you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, sorry. I was using one of the Xampp releases (as mentioned above) mostly with the default settings (IIRC) though I was using a virtual host. I believe I would have been on one of the Xampp builds that was mostly recent as of April 2013. I've since switched to a Vagrant + Docker solution using nginx.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've not given up yet; perhaps I can still figure this one out.

Comment: The problem was a mismatch of PCRE versions of the system and Apache. A `libphp5.so` rebuilt against the system `libpcre` solved it.

Answer (score -1):

i send you on example with swiftmailer:

### parameters.yml

destinatarios: [email1, email2, email3]

### services:

your service name:

```
    class: your path

    arguments: ["%destinatarios%"]
```

### the class of the service:

protected $destinatarios;

```
public function __construct($destinatarios)
{
    $this->destinatarios = $destinatarios;
}

->setCc($this->destinatarios)
```