# RFC 2822, 3.6.2 error when sending email using Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm sending an email using Laravel:

```
$userAndEmail = '"' . $user->name() . '" <' . $user->email . '>';
Mail::to($userAndEmail)->send(new UserCreated($user, $userUnencryptedPassword));
```

This is returning the following error message:
`Address in mailbox given ["Bob asdf" <rava@gmail.com>] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.`

This works if `$userAndEmail` is just an email address, such as `rava@gmail.com`. Any tips on what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963755/swift-rfccomplianceexception-on-valid-email-address-works-in-windows-not-in-ubu It seems that the regular expressions check of PCRE version can be the problem.